# WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

In the Task Manager of Windows 22H2 version 19045.3693, there are brief instances of PowerShell instances appearing and utilizing CPU resources before quickly disappearing.

I keep getting powershell/v1.0 running this script

```
-NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -InputFormat Text -OutputFormat Text -Command Get-Process -Id 4056 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HandleCount EngineVersion=5.1.19041.3693
```

Task manager  shows that this process is consuming a lot of resources especially CPU.

I can see that that System User is calling it, I just wonder how am I to disable it so it stops. Is it a virus or legitimate process?

Comment: "getting"? Where? When? Is it a popup warning message or some other notification? Does it come from a program you have started? What are your system details? Have you checked your startup tasks to see how it's starting? Use Process Explorer and/or AutoRuns, both from Microsoft SysInternals, to find how this process is starting.

Comment: Apologies. Allow me to provide additional details. In the Task Manager of Windows 22H2 version 19045.3693, there are brief instances of PowerShell instances appearing and utilizing CPU resources before quickly disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

I think i might have a found the program causing this issue it  `Get-Process -Id 4056 | Select-Object Id, ProcessName, HandleCount, StartTime` seems to be saying that a process id 4056 is the issue.

So doing `Get-Process -Id 4056 | Format-List` I found its `erl.exe` from Erlang.

Even though the problem is resolved by disabling the program, I remain uncertain about the reasons behind Erlang's peculiar behavior on this particular machine.